# Scrolling Div with overflow auto doesn't contain table when child of a fieldset

Tags: html, css, overflow

I've been looking for hours and cant' find a combination that works. The structure is basically this:

```
<fieldset style="width:100%>
<div style="overflow:auto;">
     <table><tr><td>
     lasfdklafjasdklf asldkfkladfj aklsdfalsdkfklasdjf klfj lasdfjklasdjfkl;asjd fklasj dfaj sdfj asfkj asdkfj asdkfjaskldf asdklfasklfjasdklfasdklfasdklfasdklfj asdfj 
     </td></tr></table>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

The table is much wider than the fieldset and SHOULD be contained by the div, but it's not. If I change fieldset to div, it works perfectly, but somehow when the div is a child of the fieldset, the div loses overflow control.

Every solution I've been able to find doesn't work. No clue what to do next.

EDIT: I've set "Max-width" on the scrolling container div around the table to a percentage and it's clear the percentage is based on the width of the TABLE and not the parent. How is the table taking over all style and becoming the width-setter?

Note, I do not have the option to not use Fieldsets or tables in this case.

Comment: There are errors in the style of the fieldset. Did you mean `style="width: 100%;"`? But no matter what style I use, I can't reproduce your results. Do you have extra styles, `white-space` or something somewhere?

Comment: The fieldset has some margins, box-sizing, display is inlineblock, but that's about it. If I change the display to "Table-cell" or "table" it works, but the other fieldsets expand to take up all available space like divs when I do. This also only works in Firefox.

Comment: Subsequent divs leading down to my eventual scrolling div only have font and other non-important styles.